How to access astro props inside a script tag?
I am a new user testing out Astro. I currently have the following:
index.astro
---
import App from "../components/App.astro"
import KeycloakApp from "../components/KeycloakApp.astro";
const isAuthEnabled = true;   //switch for local dev vs deployment
var isAuthenticated = true;  //placeholder for keycloak component
if (!isAuthenticated) {
    console.log("redirect")
    return Astro.redirect('/Welcome');
}
---
{isAuthEnabled ? <KeycloakApp isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} /> : <App />}

KeycloakApp.astro
---
import App from "../components/App.astro"
var {isAuthenticated} = Astro.props;
---
<!-- Keycloak wrapper of the regular App -->
<p><button id="flip">click me to flip isAuthenticated!</button></p>
<script>
    function handleClick() {
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        isAuthenticated = !{isAuthenticated};
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
    }
    document.getElementById("flip").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
</script>
{isAuthenticated && <App />}

The console shows the following error when trying to click on the button:
Uncaught ReferenceError: isAuthenticated is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.handleClick (KeycloakApp.astro:9:21)

How can I access the value of isAuthenticated inside my script? The name isAuthenticated cannot be found.

I am trying to reference the docs here 
I am trying to look for a way to access astro props inside a script tag, though if not possible whatsoever, I might just fallback to using a react component with useStates

ignore the first dollar sign in the console log. I was trying whatever I could to get it to recognize the variable, but to no avail

You probably don’t have linting support. Run the code first to check for errors.

The code runs, but doesnt really have any errors. When clicking the button, the console shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: isAuthenticated is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.handleClick (KeycloakApp.astro:9:21)

Hmm that’s weird. Remove the $ sign and check again for console errors.

i have already removed it. its just that the pic shows the dollar sign

In Astro the frontmatter is only executed server-side so the props are not available inside your script tag which is executed client side. To be able to use a prop inside the script tag, you need to use define:vars directive. See the Template Directives Reference on Astro documentation.
---
import App from "../components/App.astro"
var {isAuthenticated} = Astro.props;
---
<!-- Keycloak wrapper of the regular App -->
<p><button id="flip">click me to flip isAuthenticated!</button></p>
<script define:vars={{isAuthenticated}}>
    function handleClick() {
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        isAuthenticated = !{isAuthenticated};
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
    }
    document.getElementById("flip").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
</script>
{isAuthenticated && <App />}

The caveat is that when using define:vars, Astro will also apply the is:inline directive so your scripts won’t be bundled and will be inlined directly into the HTML.
If you don't want that behavior you could try using a data attribute on your button and read the value in your script tag. Something like (I haven't tested):
---
import App from "../components/App.astro"
var {isAuthenticated = false} = Astro.props;
---
<!-- Keycloak wrapper of the regular App -->
<p><button id="flip" data-authenticated={`${isAuthenticated}`}>click me to flip isAuthenticated!</button></p>
<script>
    function handleClick(e) {
        let isAuthenticated = Boolean(e.currentTarget.dataset.authenticated);
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        isAuthenticated = !{isAuthenticated};
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        e.currentTarget.dataset.authenticated = String(isAuthenticated);
    }
    document.getElementById("flip").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
</script>
{isAuthenticated && <App />}


it seems the first answer is probably not according to my usage, because on the browser, the inlined script becomes const isAuthenticated = false; isAuthenticated = !{isAuthenticated}; which of course is not possible and throws an uncaught type error. The second seems promising for what I need

it seems the second doesnt really work for my use case either, as the conditional rendering of the  is not affected by the flipping of the data attribute authentication. but regardless this is a good answer still, as it answered my question on how to access the astro props inside the script tag. Much appreciated

With the second example, you can show/hide the App with some inline styles. In the handleClick function, you could query the App container (by adding a class or an id for example) and add display:none; when not authenticated and remove it once authenticated. I'm not sure if this is the best approach for authentication (if <App /> require some dependent data it might not work) but for other use cases you can use this.
